# Translate Python request to an Apps Script request

Tags: python, google-apps-script, httprequest, urlfetch

I'm trying to automate an API request into Google spreadsheets using Apps Script, the GET request seems to work fine in python, but when I try to replicate the same request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` method it throws a 422 error, ignoring headers apparently.

Here is the working python code:

```
url = "https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa?access_token={}".format(token)
r = requests.get(url = caixa, params= {'data_inicio' : '2018-01-01',
                                       'data_fim' : '2022-02-01', 
                                       'regime':'caixa'})
```

But when I try to replicate it to Apps Script, it seems to ignore those parameters

```
var link = "https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa?access_token=my_access_token";

headers = {
'data_inicio': '2020-01-01',
'data_fim': '2020-06-30',
'regime': 'caixa',
};


var options = {
  "method" : "get",
  "contentType":"application/json",
  'headers': headers,
    };
  Logger.log(options);
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options)
```

It throws the following error message:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api.granatum.com.br returned code 422. Truncated server response: {"errors":{"data_inicio":["é obrigatório"],"data_fim":["é obrigatório"],"regime":["é obrigatório","inválido"]}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

Translating the response, it asks for those three parameters informed above, as if it haven't received them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the following python script to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    url = "https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa?access_token={}".format(token)
    r = requests.get(url = caixa, params= {'data_inicio' : '2018-01-01', 'data_fim' : '2022-02-01', 'regime':'caixa'})
  ```

  - In this script, `url` is `"https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa?access_token={}".format(token)`. But `requests` uses `url = caixa`. But, from your Google Apps Script, in this answer, it supposes that you are using `url`.

When you want to use `url` in above script, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your python script, it seems that the values of `params` are sent as the query parameter. But in your script, these values are sent in the request header.
- And, in the case of GET method, the content type is not required to be used.

When above points are reflected to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // This is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
  String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
    return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
      return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
        (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
          return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
        },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
    },"");
  }

  var url = "https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa";
  var query = {
    'data_inicio': '2020-01-01',
    'data_fim': '2020-06-30',
    'regime': 'caixa',
    'access_token': 'my_access_token'
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.addQuery(query));
  Logger.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your python script works fine with `url`. And, it supposes that your access token can be used. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Hi! It worked! the response is the JS object as expected! Thank you! Can you explain the String.prototype.addQuery part? I'm fairly new to Apps Script and surely want to understand it! Once again thank you!

Comment: @João Rafael Borowski Tedeschi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `String.prototype.addQuery`, this function is used for converting the JSON object to the query parameters. Because at Google Apps Script, such method is not prepared. Also, you can manually add the JSON object as the query parameter like `https://api.granatum.com.br/v1/relatorios/fluxo_caixa?data_inicio=2020-01-01&data_fim=2020-06-30&regime=caixa&access_token=my_access_token`. If this explanation is not want you want, I apologize.